# Newly Added content type is not displaying in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-list

I created one content type and i kept that in one group.
Now I created a list and enabled the 
**Allow managed content types**
for that list. Now i am trying to add that content type to my list. When i went to list settings and click on **add from existing content types** it is not displaying the newly added content type. Whats wrong in this. Did I miss any step?

Comment: What type does your content type inherit from?

Comment: I made mistake while creating the type of content type to inherit from. Got solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Not published? I know it sounds simple but check.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was alluded to in a comment, but not explicitly noted. So:

**The new content type needs to inherit from a List or Folder content type** in order to be able to add it to a List. For example, you could inherit from the "Item" content type.

If it inherits from the "Document" content type then it won't appear.